# sql snytax error, and string issue related to sqlsyntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hey guys im getting an sqlsyntax error when I add in `idWallPosting` to my select statement in my code below:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT idWallPosting, wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN User u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
    {
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            test1.Controls.Clear();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                div.Attributes["class"] = "test";


                div.ID = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
                // this line is responsible, problem here and my sqlsntax, im trying to set the SELECT idWallPosting for the div ID
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(1));

                img.AlternateText = "Test image";

                div.Controls.Add(img);
                div.Controls.Add(ParseControl(String.Format("&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;" + "{0}", reader.GetString(0))));
                div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();");

                div.Style["clear"] = "both";
                test1.Controls.Add(div);

            }
        }
    }
```

My db looks like this:

[image]

In my code im trying to set the div.ID to the current idWallPosting in my WallPosting table so im also not sure I have that correct either.

**EDIT:**

Error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Related to this line I think:

```
div.ID = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
```

Comment: let's start with, are you missing a comma after idwallposting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma. This:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT idWallPosting wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN User u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
```

Should be this:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT idWallPosting, wp.WallPostings, p.PicturePath FROM WallPosting wp LEFT JOIN User u ON u.UserID = wp.UserID LEFT JOIN Pictures p ON p.UserID = u.UserID WHERE wp.UserID=" + userId + " ORDER BY idWallPosting DESC", cn))
```

Comma: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

EDIT:

You may try [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getvalue.aspx) instead of `GetString`. The description for GetValue:

> Gets the value of the column at the specified ordinal in its native format.

Comment: haha true but I have a new error tho, so if you could also help on that ive edited my post and will give the correct answer sorry for missing that im as blind as a bat.

Comment: Is it? Half the questions on this site can be found with 5 minutes of time and [Google](http://www.google.com). People still get rep for those all the time.

Comment: Don't take that seriously, Free.  I was just joking with you as I typed essentially the same thing as a comment at the same time.  It's all good.

Comment: hey free nope same problem with GetValue or Getint32

Comment: @Graham: Try the other `GetStrings`. It seems that one of those is surely causing the problem.

Comment: no if i change the div.id to static div.ID = "bla"; all works fine but as soon as I try to set the divs id via the string it messes up, could it be the value GetString(2) im not sure if that relates to idWallPosting

Comment: its ok got it, it was the values

Comment: Was just about to post about the values I thought were messed up. Upon further inspection it seemed that the indexes were off. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

wallPosting is an int and you are using .GetString.  You should be using .GetInt32 probably.